# substr count returns wrong results

Tags: php, regex, substring

I am using substr_count to count the number of times a word was used.
  but its not returning the results I want.
here is my sample code :

```
<?php
    echo substr_count("The Hello world. Therefore the world is nice","the");
?>
```

this will return the number 3 which is 3 strings the. I want it to return only 2. since there are 2 the. the third one is a part of the word therefore so its not a the.
I thought of regular expression but I am not really good with those. any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to add space after `the`, that it could include only those `the` which has a space after it

```
  <?php
        echo substr_count("The Hello world. Therefore the world is nice","the ");
    ?>
```

Comment: what if its followed by punctuation ? like the. then it wont count it but it should count it because its still that same word.

Comment: you need to find out a way to solve someway like   `str_replace' before doing the count

Answer (score 0):

I think the usage of substr_count is different.
Syntax:

```
 int substr_count ( string $haystack , string $needle [, int $offset = 0 [, int $length ]] )
```

substr_count() returns the number of times the needle substring occurs in the haystack string. Please note that needle is case sensitive.

Please refer
http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php

Comment: any other way to achieve the results I need ? I was thinking about regular expressions are you familiar with that ?

Comment: @fogsy there is another way..please check my second answer

Answer (score 0):

there are 3 'the's .
The Therefore and the

try this:

```
<?php
   echo substr_count("The Hello world. Therefore the world is nice","the ");
?>
```

Comment: what if its followed by punctuation ? like the. then it wont count it but it should count it because its still that same word.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of counting substring occurrence,

```
<?php
 $string = "The Hello world. Therefore the world is nice";
 $substring = 'the';

 $cArr = explode($substring,strtolower($string));
 echo $substring_count = count($cArr) - 1;
?>
```

OR

```
$wordCounts = array_count_values(str_word_count(strtolower($string),1));
echo $theCount = (isset($wordCounts['the'])) ? $wordCounts['the'] : 0;
```

Comment: No.Bro its a working code.The only thing to remember is it will find the occurrence of 'the' not 'The'.

Comment: Hi @fogsy I have updated my answer.Please check it out.It is now working for both 'the' and 'The'.

Comment: @fogsy try with the second option of my answer.This will help you.Sur.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  echo preg_match_all('/\bthe\b/i', 'The Hello World. Therefore the world is nice', $m);
?>
```

First parameter is the pattern, where `\b` means word boundary, `/i` modifier means case-in-sensitiveness.

Second parameter is the subject of matching.

Third parameter is filled with an array of matches. My old PHP requires it, versions since 5.4 shouldn't require it.